# pass list as a argument to spark sql statement

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking to pass list as a parameter to sparksql statement.

```
process_date = '2020-01-01'

df1 = spark.sql("""select '{0}', * from table1""".format(process_date))

This works for a string. 
So df1 is created successfully.
```

```
But If I have List like this 

list1 = ['a','b','c']

df2 = spark.sql("""select '{0}','{1}',* from table1""".format(process_date,list1))

This is not working for me.
```

Comment: you can convert the list to string using `join` on the list

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join` and list comprehension to get the following sql statement

```
"select '2020-01-01','a','b','c',* from table1"
```

```
print("""select '{0}',{1},* from table1""".format(process_date,",".join((f"'{i}'" for i in list1))))
```

Comment: ```list1 = ['a','b','c']

df1 = spark.sql("""select * from table1""".format(",".join((f'"{i}"' for i in list1))))
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Comment: I am using python version Python version 2.7.16.